# Trying to add Selected Attribute to dropdown populated by while statement with array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a form with a drop-down menu that is populated by a while statement, pulling an array from a database in mysql. I am trying to add a selected attribute for one of the options, which I have stored elsewhere on the page in the variable $inv_item["type"]

```
function find_all_types() {
    global $connection;

    $query  = "SELECT type ";
    $query .= "FROM types ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY id ASC";
    $type_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($type_set);
    return $type_set;
}

       <select name="type">
           <?php
               $type_set = find_all_types();
               while ($type = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_set)){ 
           ?>
           <option value= "<?php echo $type['type'] ?>"><?php echo $type['type'] ?></option>
           <?php } ?>
       </select>
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this, or if I can make it work using this while statement. It was pretty hard to research this, I couldn't find the same situation, most search results people were populating their drop-down menus with individually written options.

I am aware that mysql commands are deprecated, working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you could do it as a comparison in the option:

<option value= "<?php echo $type['type'] ?>" <?php if($type['type'] == $inv_item["type"]){echo" selected";}?>><?php echo $type['type'] ?></option>
```

but it looks pretty messy - jumping in  and out of php - I would stay in it:

```
        <?php
               $type_set = find_all_types();
               while ($type = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_set)){ 

          $type_item = $type['type'];

          echo"<option value= '".$type_item."'";
           if($type_item == $inv_item["type"]){echo" selected";}
         echo" >".$type_item."</option>";
           } 
?>
```

Comment: That was it! way to make me feel dumb for not thinking of it! thanks!

Comment: no probs @Michael Bourbonnais - check my edited answer - i think it would make it nicer if it as wall in the php section, but thats just me. :))

Comment: your'e welcome  - please click the accept answer tick if this helped you so that others can see it has been resolved. Happy Coding :))

Comment: I like that, I'll probably use it. I learned everything I know from a tutorial on lynda and just messing around with code myself, so it's nice to get a new perspective.